# Kubernetes DNS works where kube-dns pod working, if scale kubedns pod nothing is working

Tags: kubernetes

```
Kubernetes version (use kubectl version):
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.0", GitCommit:"87d9d8d7bc5aa35041a8ddfe3d4b367381112f89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-12T21:10:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.0", GitCommit:"87d9d8d7bc5aa35041a8ddfe3d4b367381112f89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-12T21:10:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Environment:

```
AWS, using VPC, all master and 2 nodes under same subnet
RHEL 7.2
Kernel (e.g. uname -a): Linux master.example.com 3.10.0-514.6.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 17 19:21:31 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Install tools: Install kubernetes as per Redhat guideline using flannel Network
flannel-config.json
{
"Network": "10.20.0.0/16",
"SubnetLen": 24,
"Backend": {
"Type": "vxlan",
"VNI": 1
}
}
Kubernetes Cluster Network : 10.254.0.0/16
```

Others:
What happened:
We have kubernetes cluster setup with following setup

```
Master: ip-10-52-2-56.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal
Node1: ip-10-52-2-59.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal
Node2: ip-10-52-2-54.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal
```

Master config details:

```
[root@master ~]# egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/etcd/etcd.conf
ETCD_NAME=default
ETCD_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/etcd/default.etcd"
ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS="http://localhost:2380"
ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:2379"
ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:2379"
[root@master ~]# egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/kubernetes/config
KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR="--logtostderr=true"
KUBE_LOG_LEVEL="--v=0"
KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV="--allow-privileged=false"
KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://ip-10-52-2-56.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal:8080"
[root@master ~]# egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/kubernetes/apiserver
KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--address=0.0.0.0"
KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd_servers=http://ip-10-52-2-56.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal:2379"
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16"
KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL="--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota"
KUBE_API_ARGS="--service_account_key_file=/serviceaccount.key""
[root@master ~]# egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/sysconfig/flanneld
FLANNEL_ETCD="http://ip-10-52-2-56.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal:2379"
FLANNEL_ETCD_KEY="/coreos.com/network"
FLANNEL_OPTIONS="eth0"

Node1/Node2 config details are same as follows:
[root@ip-10-52-2-59 ec2-user]# egrep -v '^$|^#' /etc/kubernetes/config
KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR="--logtostderr=true"
KUBE_LOG_LEVEL="--v=0"
KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV="--allow-privileged=false"
KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://ip-10-52-2-56.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal:8080"
[root@ip-10-52-2-59 ec2-user]# egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/kubernetes/kubelet
KUBELET_ADDRESS="--address=0.0.0.0"
KUBELET_HOSTNAME="--hostname-override=ip-10-52-2-59.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal"
KUBELET_API_SERVER="--api-servers=http://ip-10-52-2-56.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal:8080"
KUBELET_POD_INFRA_CONTAINER="--pod-infra-container-image=registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/pod-infrastructure:latest"
KUBELET_ARGS="--cluster-dns=10.254.0.2 --cluster-domain=cluster.local"
[root@ip-10-52-2-59 ec2-user]# grep KUBE_PROXY_ARGS /etc/kubernetes/proxy
KUBE_PROXY_ARGS=""
[root@ip-10-52-2-59 ec2-user]# egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/sysconfig/flanneld
FLANNEL_ETCD="http://ip-10-52-2-56.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal:2379"
FLANNEL_ETCD_KEY="/coreos.com/network"
FLANNEL_OPTIONS="eth0"
```

Running kube dns as below configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: kube-dns
namespace: kube-system
labels:
k8s-app: kube-dns
kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
kubernetes.io/name: "KubeDNS"
spec:
selector:
k8s-app: kube-dns
clusterIP: 10.254.0.2
ports:

name: dns
port: 53
protocol: UDP
name: dns-tcp
port: 53
protocol: TCP
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
labels:
k8s-app: kube-dns
kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
version: v20
name: kube-dns-v20
namespace: kube-system
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
k8s-app: kube-dns
version: v20
template:
metadata:
labels:
k8s-app: kube-dns
kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
version: v20
spec:
containers:
-
args:
- "--domain=cluster.local"
- "--kube-master-url=http://ip-10-52-2-56.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal:8080"
- "--dns-port=10053"
image: "gcr.io/google_containers/kubedns-amd64:1.9"
livenessProbe:
failureThreshold: 5
httpGet:
path: /healthz
port: 8080
scheme: HTTP
initialDelaySeconds: 60
successThreshold: 1
timeoutSeconds: 5
name: kubedns
ports:
-
containerPort: 10053
name: dns-local
protocol: UDP
-
containerPort: 10053
name: dns-tcp-local
protocol: TCP
readinessProbe:
httpGet:
path: /readiness
port: 8081
scheme: HTTP
initialDelaySeconds: 30
timeoutSeconds: 5
resources:
limits:
cpu: 100m
memory: 500Mi
requests:
cpu: 100m
memory: 500Mi
-
args:
- "--cache-size=1000"
- "--no-resolv"
- "--server=127.0.0.1#10053"
image: "gcr.io/google_containers/kube-dnsmasq-amd64:1.4"
name: dnsmasq
ports:
-
containerPort: 53
name: dns
protocol: UDP
-
containerPort: 53
name: dns-tcp
protocol: TCP
-
args:
- "-cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1 >/dev/null && nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:10053 >/dev/null"
- "-port=8080"
- "-quiet"
image: "gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz-amd64:1.2"
name: healthz
ports:
-
containerPort: 8080
protocol: TCP
resources:
limits:
cpu: 10m
memory: 20Mi
requests:
cpu: 10m
memory: 20Mi
dnsPolicy: Default
```

What happen:
Kubernetes DNS works where kube-dns pod working, if scale kubedns pod nothing is working anywhere (nodes).

In below one dns pod is running on node1 and response also coming from node1 busybox pod but node2 busybox pod nslookup not responded.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cptjX.png)

Now below two dns pods are running on node1 and node2 and you can see NO response coming from none of busybox pod from both node

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utKS9.png)

below some other observation ....

**DNS pod most of the time taking 172.17 IP series if i scale more than 4 pod then in node 2 dns pod taking 10.20 series IP.**

Interesting part Node2 pods started with 10.20 series IP.
but Node1 pods started with 172.17 series IP.

Some of iptable-save output for both nodes.

```
[root@ip-10-52-2-54 ec2-user]# iptables-save | grep DNAT
-A KUBE-SEP-3M72SO5X7J6X6TX6 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/prometheus:prometheus" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.8:9090
-A KUBE-SEP-7SLC3EUJVX23N2X4 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/zookeeper:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:2181
-A KUBE-SEP-D4NTKJJ3YXXGJARZ -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.10:53
-A KUBE-SEP-EN24FH2N7PLAR6AW -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kafkacluster:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:9092
-A KUBE-SEP-LCDAFU4UXQHVDQT6 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -m recent --set --name KUBE-SEP-LCDAFU4UXQHVDQT6 --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.52.2.56:6443
-A KUBE-SEP-MX63IHIHS5ZB4347 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nodejs4promethus-scraping:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.6:3000
-A KUBE-SEP-NOI5B75N7ZJAIPJR -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongodb-prometheus-exporter:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.12:9001
-A KUBE-SEP-O6UDQQL3MHGYTSH5 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/producer:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:8125
-A KUBE-SEP-QO4SWWCV7NMMGPBN -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kafka-prometheus-jmx:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:7071
-A KUBE-SEP-SVCEI2UVU246H7MW -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongodb:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.12:27017
-A KUBE-SEP-Y4XH6F2KQCY7WQBG -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.10:53
-A KUBE-SEP-ZXXWX3EF7T3W7UNY -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/grafana:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.9:3000

[root@ip-10-52-2-54 ec2-user]# iptables-save | grep 53
-A KUBE-SEP-D4NTKJJ3YXXGJARZ -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.10:53
-A KUBE-SEP-Y4XH6F2KQCY7WQBG -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.10:53
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.254.0.2/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.254.0.2/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4

---------

[root@ip-10-52-2-59 ec2-user]# iptables-save | grep DNAT
-A KUBE-SEP-3M72SO5X7J6X6TX6 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/prometheus:prometheus" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.8:9090
-A KUBE-SEP-7SLC3EUJVX23N2X4 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/zookeeper:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:2181
-A KUBE-SEP-D4NTKJJ3YXXGJARZ -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.10:53
-A KUBE-SEP-EN24FH2N7PLAR6AW -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kafkacluster:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:9092
-A KUBE-SEP-LCDAFU4UXQHVDQT6 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -m recent --set --name KUBE-SEP-LCDAFU4UXQHVDQT6 --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.52.2.56:6443
-A KUBE-SEP-MX63IHIHS5ZB4347 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nodejs4promethus-scraping:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.6:3000
-A KUBE-SEP-NOI5B75N7ZJAIPJR -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongodb-prometheus-exporter:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.12:9001
-A KUBE-SEP-O6UDQQL3MHGYTSH5 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/producer:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:8125
-A KUBE-SEP-QO4SWWCV7NMMGPBN -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kafka-prometheus-jmx:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:7071
-A KUBE-SEP-SVCEI2UVU246H7MW -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongodb:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.12:27017
-A KUBE-SEP-Y4XH6F2KQCY7WQBG -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.10:53
-A KUBE-SEP-ZXXWX3EF7T3W7UNY -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/grafana:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.9:3000

[root@ip-10-52-2-59 ec2-user]# iptables-save | grep 53

-A KUBE-SEP-D4NTKJJ3YXXGJARZ -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.10:53
-A KUBE-SEP-Y4XH6F2KQCY7WQBG -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.10:53
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.254.0.2/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.254.0.2/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU
```

---

```
Restarted below serviced on both node

    for SERVICES in flanneld docker kube-proxy.service kubelet.service; do
    systemctl stop $SERVICES
    systemctl start $SERVICES
    done

Node1: ifconfig

    [root@ip-10-52-2-59 ec2-user]# ifconfig
    docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
            inet6 fe80::42:2dff:fe01:c0b0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 02:42:2d:01:c0:b0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 1718522  bytes 154898857 (147.7 MiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 1704874  bytes 2186333188 (2.0 GiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
            inet 10.52.2.59  netmask 255.255.255.224  broadcast 10.52.2.63
            inet6 fe80::91:9aff:fe7e:20a7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 02:91:9a:7e:20:a7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 2604083  bytes 2208387383 (2.0 GiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 1974861  bytes 593497458 (566.0 MiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
            inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
            inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
            loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
            RX packets 80  bytes 7140 (6.9 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 80  bytes 7140 (6.9 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    veth01225a6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::1034:a8ff:fe79:aba3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 12:34:a8:79:ab:a3  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 1017  bytes 100422 (98.0 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 1869  bytes 145519 (142.1 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    veth3079eb6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::90c2:62ff:fe84:fb53  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 92:c2:62:84:fb:53  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 4891  bytes 714845 (698.0 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 5127  bytes 829516 (810.0 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    veth3be8c1f: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::c8a5:64ff:fe15:be95  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether ca:a5:64:15:be:95  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 210  bytes 27750 (27.0 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 307  bytes 35118 (34.2 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    veth559a1ab: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::100b:23ff:fe60:3752  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 12:0b:23:60:37:52  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 14926  bytes 1931413 (1.8 MiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 14375  bytes 19695295 (18.7 MiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    veth5c05729: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::cca1:4ff:fe5d:14cd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether ce:a1:04:5d:14:cd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 455  bytes 797963 (779.2 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 681  bytes 83904 (81.9 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    veth85ba9a9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::74ca:90ff:feae:6f4d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 76:ca:90:ae:6f:4d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 19  bytes 1404 (1.3 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 66  bytes 4568 (4.4 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    vetha069d16: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::accd:eeff:fe21:6eda  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether ae:cd:ee:21:6e:da  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 3566  bytes 7353788 (7.0 MiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 2560  bytes 278400 (271.8 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    vetha58e4af: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::6cd2:16ff:fee2:aa59  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 6e:d2:16:e2:aa:59  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 779  bytes 62585 (61.1 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 1014  bytes 109417 (106.8 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    vethb7bbef5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::5ce6:6fff:fe31:c3e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 5e:e6:6f:31:0c:3e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 589  bytes 55654 (54.3 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 573  bytes 74014 (72.2 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    vethbda3e0a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::9c0a:f2ff:fea5:23a2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 9e:0a:f2:a5:23:a2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 490  bytes 47064 (45.9 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 645  bytes 77464 (75.6 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    vethfc65cc3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet6 fe80::b854:dcff:feb4:f4ba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether ba:54:dc:b4:f4:ba  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 503  bytes 508251 (496.3 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 565  bytes 73145 (71.4 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


    Node2 - ifconfig

    [root@ip-10-52-2-54 ec2-user]# ifconfig
    docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 8951
            inet 10.20.48.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
            inet6 fe80::42:87ff:fe39:2ef0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 02:42:87:39:2e:f0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 269123  bytes 22165441 (21.1 MiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 419870  bytes 149980299 (143.0 MiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
            inet 10.52.2.54  netmask 255.255.255.224  broadcast 10.52.2.63
            inet6 fe80::9a:d8ff:fed3:4cf5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 02:9a:d8:d3:4c:f5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 1517512  bytes 938147149 (894.6 MiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 1425156  bytes 1265738472 (1.1 GiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    flannel.1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 8951
            inet 10.20.48.0  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
            ether 06:69:bf:c6:8a:12  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
            TX errors 0  dropped 1 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
            inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
            inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
            loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
            RX packets 106  bytes 8792 (8.5 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 106  bytes 8792 (8.5 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    veth9f05785: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 8951
            inet6 fe80::d81e:d3ff:fe5e:bade  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether da:1e:d3:5e:ba:de  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 31  bytes 2458 (2.4 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 37  bytes 4454 (4.3 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

little confused with two ifconfig output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check flanneld process on node-1, flannel.1 interface is missing from node-1, check /var/log/message and also compare both node flannel config file -- /etc/sysconfig/flannel

Comment: Issue resolved ... looks like problem in network interface.

@pawankkamboj for pointing me right direction.  Thanks Alexander

Answer (score 0):

It looks like flannel is not running properly on node2. You should check the logs and configs as already pointed out by Pawan.

Also, you seem to be using an older version of Kubernetes. The current version is 1.5 and I'd recommend to use this version.

The bare metal setup guides found in the net tend to get outdated pretty fast, even the official Kubernetes guides.

I'd recommend to not use any of these guides anymore and instead use a (semi) automated deployment solution, like [kargo (Ansible based)](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kargo/) or [kops (only AWS, Go based)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops). If you do not want to use these automatic solutions, you could try to use [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/), which is currently in alpha state but may already work good enough for you.